# Hide label/button when it's beyond the parent view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, label

I'm currently testing a UI element on tableview. There is view top of the tableview. So I've added a child view on that main view and added a label on the child view.When I'm scrolling the tableview,it calculate the content offset and change the parent view height. So I need to hide the label when it's beyond the boundaries of parent view, But it's keep showing the table. How can I make invisible label when it's beyond the parent view boundaries ?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
view.clipsToBounds = true
```

or you can tick that on storyboard

[image]

this line forbid any subview from your tableview to go outside of the tableview frame.

Comment: Done, if you find the answer true please mark it as correct :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
tableView.clipsToBounds = true
```

or

```
cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = true
```